# Finding filepath of an UIImage in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app you pick an image using UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, so I have an UIImage. Now I need the filepath of said image.

More about the app: I'm trying to modify/edit a selected PNG image. I need to be able to access each pixel of chosen image. I have found source code on how to access the pixels but the code relies on loading the image via filepath and I haven't found any way of using the UIImage instead. I've tried:

```
CGImageRef si = [imageView.image CGImage];
CGDataProviderRef src = CGImageGetDataProvider(si);
CGImageRef img = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(src, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

But that only gives me the error: ": CGDataProviderGetSize: size is too large for this function."

(See [iPhone SDK: accessing indexed color PNG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251595/iphone-sdk-accessing-indexed-color-png-images) )

Answer (score 1):

When the image is picked, your delegate gets a callback on imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:  That call includes an [info parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a) which is a dictionary.  One of the [keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys) gives you the file URL.  A file URL can be converted to a path using the [path](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) method.

Comment: I saw in the documentation that that method signature was deprecated but using the correct signature `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`
only gives me the keys and values "key: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType, value: public.image
key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, value: <UIImage: 0x392e680>"