# How do I modify the palette of an indexed PNG at runtime on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, png, core-graphics, cgcolorspace

I have a series of PNG images that use indices into a palette for color (PNG color type 3). In some cases, I need to make a copy of an image where some of the entries in the palette are modified. In this way we recolor a source PNG over and over.

In Java, this is handled by getting the RGB values from an `IndexedColorModel`, modifying the values and creating a new `IndexedColorModel`, and creating a new `BufferedImage` with the source image's raster data and the new color model.

In Actionscript, I had to read in the PNG bytes as a bare `ByteArray`, find the palette chunk, modify the values, then have the runtime load up the image from the `ByteArray`.

I'm now looking to implement the same system for iOS via MonoTouch (which I'm new to), but I've hit a wall. I believe the Actionscript approach would work here as well, but it would be nice to avoid working at such a low level this time, and it looks like I can get close.

If I'm starting from a `UIImage`, I can get the color space with `UIImage.CGImage.ColorSpace`. I can verify that it's an indexed color model with `colorSpace.Model`. What I'm not sure about is how I get the actual array of palette bytes.

And then on the other side, how do I create a new image with the new palette? `CGImage.WithColorSpace` looks like it would do what I want... maybe? And then I have to be able to create a color space with my new palette: On the surface, `CGColorSpace.CreateIndexed` looks like what I want, but I'm unclear on how the `baseSpace` parameter is used. I want to create a `CGColorSpace` with a totally new color palette that I provide, and then use the original image's indices with the new palette. Maybe I'm misunderstanding exactly what `CGColorSpace` is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Actionscript, I had to read in the PNG bytes as a bare ByteArray, find the palette chunk, modify the values, then have the runtime load up the image from the ByteArray.

That's a bit brute but it would work. However I'm pretty sure CoreGraphics has everything you need to avoid this.

> If I'm starting from a UIImage

Since you'll be using CoreGraphics (CG) anyway you can start with a `CGImage`. Sample code (objc) here: [iPhone SDK: accessing indexed color PNG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251595/iphone-sdk-accessing-indexed-color-png-images)

> What I'm not sure about is how I get the actual array of palette bytes.

[`CGColorSpaceGetColorTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408853-cgcolorspacegetcolortable) looks like the perfect candidate. However it looks like it's missing from MonoTouch bindings (I'll check that) but it would be easy (it's a p/invoke) to bind manually and use in your application.

> but I'm unclear on how the baseSpace parameter is used

[`CGColorSpace.CreateIndexed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408899-cgcolorspacecreateindexed) can accept a `null` parameter for `baseSpace` but you might be better copying the same, base, GCColorSpace from the original PNG image.

Comment: p.s. if you can fill a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com foir the missing `CGColorSpaceGetColorTable` and attach an indexed PNG I'll add it to the next (stable) MonoTouch release. The p/invoke declaration will end in github's (public) maccore repository (so you'll be able to copy/paste it from there). Thanks!

Comment: Aha, a missing method. I'll submit a bug report today. Also, I didn't mention this because I wasn't sure it would be pertinent, but I'm actually working with an *additional* layer: my source is actually in Java, converted to a DLL via IKVM. I don't know (yet) how to do a manual binding, and then if I'll be able to access it via IKVM, but I will go investigate in that direction now. Thanks!

Comment: Bug submitted with attached example image: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4573. Hopefully I'll have time to dig into manual binding today, will report back on success then.

Comment: Thanks! That would make a much better test case :-) The declaration can be seen from https://github.com/mono/maccore/commit/e9fd100d474522c1973c56a4a30d026f52f89ab9 but you'll likely require a bit more of C# to get this going thru IKVM.

Comment: Marking this answered: I'm convinced all the pieces I need are where I can see them now. Haven't had a chance to play with it yet, and rather than try to get a manual binding accessible through IKVM, I'm just going to wait for the next MonoTouch release :). Thanks for the help!